# Provided smooth scroll for anchor links on website but now cannot access external links

Tags: html, jquery

I have a little interesting problem on my website.

I will provide you the URL to the website and then if you follow the directions below, you can see my issue.

https://www.metis-online.com

Instructions:

1. Load the website
2. On the navbar menu, select any link and you can see it performs a
   smooth scroll. Can select on any links in that navbar menu and it works as
   expected where it scrolls to the relevant section on the page.
3. We are now going to access an external link so perform the
   following: Select 'Courses' from the nav bar menu and then select
   'Order our online course and exam bundle'. You should be taken to the
   relevant page which is an external page.
4. Now on that page, select any of the navbar links and you can see
   nothing happens and the console displays an error stating it can't
   find #top.

That's the issue I am facing. I want to get a smooth scroll to work but in doing so it has broken the navbar links on external pages from the homepage.

I want the navbar links to work so that if the user is on any external page and selects any of the navbar links, it will take the user to the correct anchor of the website on the home page.

Below is the code that performs the smooth scrolling:

head.php:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $('a[href^="/../#"]').on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});

    </script>
```

header.php

```
<!-----NavigationBar---->

<section id="top">
</section>

<section id="nav-bar">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
 
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#top">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#about">ABOUT</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#courses">COURSES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#services">SERVICES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/../#testimonials">TESTIMONIALS</a>
              </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#contact">CONTACT</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</section>
```

home.php (this is the homepage and contains the anchor links to smooth scroll to, I included a button that takes the user to an external page just like the instructions):

```
<html>

<head>

 <?php include "./head.php" ?>
</head>

<body>

 <?php include "./header.php" ?>

    <!-------About------->
    <section id="about">
    ...
    </section>
    <!-------Courses------->
    <section id="courses">
    ...
    <a href="courses/course-BRFAITC009">
    <button type="button">Order online course and exam bundle</button>
    </a>
    ...
    </section>
    <!-------Services------->
    <section id="services">
    ...
    </section>
    <!-------Testimonials------->
    <section id="testimonials">
    ...
    </section>
    <!-------Contacts------->
    <section id="contacts">
    ...
    </section>

...

</body>
</html>
```

Directory -> courses/course-BRFAITC009.php

```
<html>

<head>

 <?php include "./head.php" ?>
</head>

<body>

 <?php include "./header.php" ?>

...

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cant' find 'View our online course and exam bundle' or any other external link, but it works for the footer links for me – probably because they don't have hashes in it, so my guess is that you should check for the `window.location.hostname` as well in your jquery

Comment: @davbuc Sorry I meant 'Order our online course and exam bundle'. It's a blue button. Can you show me an example in your answer please and then I will apply it to the code :)

Comment: okay so you mean the button which leads to this url: https://www.metis-online.com/courses/course-BRFAITC009 ? This is working fine for me as well

Comment: @davbuc Yes if you click on that button, it takes you to the link you mentioned. But now on thart webpage, click on any nav bar menu link (home, about, courses, services, testimonials, contact) and you can see nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your jquery code looks for the anchor in the DOM, but the anchors are not there on the subpages, so it fails as seen in the browser console. You probably need to add something like:

`if(window.location.pathname === "/") { ... rest of jquery }`

to run this code only on the homepage.